# Show that the Cantor-Lebesgue function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Show that the Cantor-Lebesgue function is continuous.

If $x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}$ is an element of the Cantor set, then the Cantor-Lebesgue function maps $x$ to

$$ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}$$

For $x$ not in the Cantor set, there's a unique interval $x\in I_n = (X_n,Y_n)$ and so we set $g(x) = g(Y_n)$.

The aim is to prove $g$ is continuous.

Here's my attempt. If $x \not \in \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set, then $g(x)$ is constant on an interval $I_n$ for some $n$ so it's continuous at $x$.

Let's take $x\in \mathcal{C}$ such that $$x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}$$

First, let's assume that $x$ doesn't have a terminating ternary representation (i.e, it has a unique ternary representation), this implies that for some $m$, $b_m=0$ and $b_{m+1}=1$. Let $m$ be large enough that $\epsilon>\dfrac{1}{2^m}$. Observe that if we pick $y$ such that $0<|x-y|<\dfrac{1}{3^{m+1}}$, we obtain

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}+\dfrac{1}{3^{m+1}}<x,y<\sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}+\dfrac{2}{3^{m}} $$

since $\dfrac{1}{3^{m+1}} = \sum_{n=m+2}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{3^n}$

$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\sum_{n=m+2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}<g(x),g(y)< \sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$$

which results in
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^{m+1}}<g(x),g(y)< \sum_{n=1}^{m}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^m}
$$

As a result, $|g(x)-g(y)|<\dfrac{1}{2^m}<\epsilon$.

A similar argument works even when $x$ has a terminating representation where all of it's ternery places are either $0$ or $2$. In this case,

$$x = \sum_{n=1}^{\ell} \dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}$$ where $b_\ell=1$

Setting $m = \max\{\ell, -\lfloor \log_{3}(\epsilon) \rfloor\}+1$, we see that $|x-y|<\dfrac{1}{3^m}$ implies

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1} \dfrac{2b_n}{3^n} + \dfrac{1}{3^\ell}+\sum_{n=\ell+1}^{m} \dfrac{2}{3^n}<x,y<\sum_{n=1}^{\ell} \dfrac{2b_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2}{3^n}$$

As a result, we see that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1} \dfrac{b_n}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{2^\ell}< g(x),g(y) < \sum_{n=1}^{\ell} \dfrac{b_n}{2^n} + \dfrac{1}{2^{m+1}}$$

and so $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$

Finally, let's suppose that $x$ has a terminating ternary representation and has $1$ at the end of its ternary point, then after some $\ell$, $b_\ell=0$ and $b_k=1$ for $k\ge \ell$:

$$
x = \sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n} + \sum_{n=\ell+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2}{3^n}
$$

Set $m = \max\{\ell, -\lfloor \log_{3}(\epsilon) \rfloor\}+1$, and if we now pick $y$ such that $0<|x-y|<\dfrac{1}{3^m}$, then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}+\sum_{n=\ell}^{m}\dfrac{2}{3^{n}}<x,y<\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\dfrac{2b_n}{3^n}+\dfrac{1}{3^{\ell}}+\dfrac{1}{3^m} $$

And so,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\sum_{n=\ell}^{m}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}< g(x),g(y) <  \sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n}+\dfrac{1}{2^{\ell}}$$

As a result,

$$|g(x)-g(y)|<\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}=\dfrac{1}{2^m}\le \epsilon$$

And so we are done!
Is this proof correct? This might be an elementary problem but I am highly inexperienced with real analysis.

I am aware there are other posts about this problem but I am only asking for proof verification not for a proof of the statement. If my proof is wrong, I do not want to see other proofs, I want to attempt the problem again.

Comment: The gist of your argument is correct, but a couple of details need correcting/expanding upon.
1) Why does the unique interval $I_n$ exist? Look at the ternary expansions of the endpoints of an interval $(a,b) \in C^c$, and the binary expansions returned after applying $g$.
2) You are fixing $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and only considering $0 < \epsilon < 1/2^m$. You need to consider all $\epsilon > 0$. Varying $m$ will do this, but I'm concerned that as written your proof does not consider all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: It's not correct, inyour estimate of $\lvert g(x) - g(y)\rvert$ you need $\epsilon > \frac{1}{2^m}$. You picked/introduced things in the wrong order. **First** you are given an $\epsilon > 0$. *Then* you choose $m$ (and you do it such that $\frac{1}{2^m} < \epsilon$, not the other way round), and then you can take $\delta < \frac{1}{3^m}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that was a typo, I fixed it now. Thank you for your feedback. Anything else I should fix?

Comment: @bounceback Could you kindly point them out?

Comment: Okay, but you cannot fix $m$ before $\epsilon$ is given. First $\epsilon$, then $m$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not understand why I can't. Why should it matter since I am picking $m$ arbitrarily?

Comment: Your proof seems to show that $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]\setminus\mathcal{C}$ and that the restriction of $g$ to $\mathcal{C}$ is continuous.  How do you want to conclude $g$ itself is continuous on $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I do not think I am restricting to $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Lesbegue -> Lebesgue

Comment: @bounceback I meant $\epsilon>1/2^m$. The unique interval exists by construction of the Cantor set.

Comment: Yes, you are restricting to $\mathcal{C}$, precisely when you say "then $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ must be identical for $x$ and $y$"?  How do you define $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ for $y$ when $y\not\in\mathcal{C}$?  There are a couple simple ways to patch this hole, but denying there's a hole isn't a good way to start.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I guess that's poor explanation on my part. I should say the first $1/3, \ldots, 1/3^m$ must have identical coefficients, otherwise the difference will exceed the bound $\delta$. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could you please explain why the statement is false? If the coefficients are not identical then there will be $1/3^k$ term with $k<m$, and so that will exceed the bound $\delta$. This was my reason.

Comment: E.g. In **any** neighborhood of $1/3$, there will be numbers $x, y$ such that none of the ternary coefficients of $1/3, 1/3^2, $ are identical.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you very much for your feedback. I learned a lot from it. I've updated the proof and I think I have patched the hole in the argument. I would love to hear your take on my current approach